# Path not found when running the program

Tags: vb6

This code is for updating the database, but every time I click the “start update” button, a “PATH NOT FOUND” error is shown.

```
Dim strEmpFileName As String
Dim strBackSlash As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr As Integer
Dim strEmpFileName1 As String
Dim strBackSlash1 As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr1 As Integer
Dim fPath As New FileSystemObject
Dim strEmpFileName2 As String
Dim strBackSlash2 As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr2 As Integer

Dim strEmpFileName21 As String
Dim strBackSlash21 As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr21 As Integer

Dim strEmpFileName21X As String
Dim strBackSlash21X As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr21X As Integer

Dim strEmpFileName21s As String
Dim strBackSlash21s As String
Dim intEmpFileNbr21s As Integer


strBackSlash = IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) = "\", "", "\")
strEmpFileName = App.Path & strBackSlash & "\SOURCE\SWA.exe"
txtSource.Text = strEmpFileName

FileCopy txtSource.Text, "\\Mainfile\SSMS_UPDATE\SHIPS ACCOUNTING\SWA.exe"
FileCopy txtSource.Text, "C:\SANKO PROGRAM\SPECIAL WORK\SWA.exe"
```

Comment: Can you add some debug print statements to figure out which path is not found?

Comment: Also, all the variable declarations are completely irrelevant to your question. On the other hand, knowing what is in `App.Path` is very relevant. Figure out what `strEmpFileName` is, and check whether it is there or not is the first step, no?

Comment: To begin with, it would be nice to tell us which line causes the error and which file isn’t found.

Comment: The system encountered an error (path not found)

Comment: does the file strEmpFileName exist? do the destination files exist? are the destination files not open or running? are you sure the network path is correct? does it work when you manually go to the network path before you run your program?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already checking for a backslash in

```
strBackSlash = IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) = "\", "", "\")
strEmpFileName = App.Path & strBackSlash & "\SOURCE\SWA.exe"
```

You should not need the backslash at the start of `"\SOURCE\SWA.exe"`

Answer (score -1):

You are misusing the IIf function. **Syntax, IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)**. Your statement checks for a backslash and if the last character is "\", sets your variable to an empty string. But the false part sets the variable to "\" if it is not the last character in your path. For example, if App.Path = *C:\MyApplication* your IIF function would set strBackSlash = "\" and strEmpFileName will be *C:\MyApplication\\SOURCE\SWA.exe*.For your code you want to use a regular **If** statement to replace the backslash character with an empty string, then use the hard-coded backslash when you build the path.

```
strAppPath = App.Path
If(Right$(strAppPath, 1) = "\" Then
    strAppPath = Left$(strAppPath, Len(strAppPath) - 1)
End Id
strEmpFileName = strAppPath & "\SOURCE\SWA.exe"
```

The full [MSDN documentation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445024%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Also, getting the application path is something that is done a lot. I suggest you write your own function to do this and add it to a project .bas file. Then you call the function from where ever you need it and the returned path format, (with or without the trailing backslash) is consistent. My personal function makes sure I have a trailing backslash.

```
Public Function AppPath() As String
    Dim sAppPath As String

    sAppPath = App.Path
    If Right$(sAppPath, 1) <> "\" Then  'check that I'm not in the root
        sAppPath = sAppPath & "\"
    End If

    AppPath = sAppPath

End Function
```

*useage:* `strEmpFileName = AppPath() & "SOURCE\SWA.exe"`